# DISCORD: Delete Discord messages that contain blacklisted words with a python script

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing a script to delete Discord messages that contain blacklisted words, but can't get it to work. I succeeded in writing a ping, but not on messages deletion and no error is displayed in the console:

```
# ----- Imports -----
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# ----- Variables -----
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 't.')

blacklist = [
"nigger",
"nigga",
"slut",
"whore",
"cum",
"pussy",
"dick",
"penis",
"vagina",
"cock",
"faggot",
"nig",
"fag"
"test"]


# ----- Functions -----

# Function that runs when bot is logged in and ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')
    activity = discord.Game(name="t.ping")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)

# Ping command
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency) * 1000}ms')

# function for deleting messages
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    for word in blacklist:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.delete(message)
            await message.channel.send("Test")

# Token
client.run('TOKEN_STRING')
```

The 'TOKEN_STRING' is replaced for an authentication token in the real application.

I am not sure how to test word presence in the message content. Things I tried are:

- `if word in message.content:`
- `word in message.content`
- `message.content == word`
- ...

but nothing solved the issue so far. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, I ensured to shorted the list of words in blacklist so it's easier to read. If you need any further explanation at any point of this, do let me know, but the code below should be pretty straight forward.

```py
blacklist = [
  "test",
  "panic",
  "five"
]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if any(word in message.content for word in blacklist):
    await message.delete()
    await message.channel.send("That word is not allowed :(")
```